# Image appears in edit mode in ckeditor but not on  production site

Tags: 7, entities

I am using Drupal-6 with ckeditor.

Now Image appears in edit mode in ckeditor but not on Home Page

Does anybody have idea what was the exact  problem ??

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is the word 'not' missing from your question in several places by any chance?

Comment: This trips me up sometime when I am saving a node with the wrong filter. Try saving with FULL HTML and see if it makes a difference. Is <img> part of your allowed HTML tags?

Comment: Yes, i used Full HTMl too. Still Not working ...